# TeamCity Module 'C' should be referenced

Tags: c#, razor, teamcity-8.0

I am trying to set up TeamCity with a single project to start with.

Everything seems to work well except for when I add an “Inspections (.NET)” build step. I am getting a `Module 'C' should be referenced` error every time there is an `@` in a .cshtml file.

How can I configure TeamCity to work correctly with .cshtml?